# How to generate and keep track of a running number/id in a Functional Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a set of buttons in a React Functional Component, one called "Generate A" and another called "Generate B", "Generate C" etc.

Each time one of them is clicked, would like to generate a set of new IDs in running order, and append to a list (the list is kept in a `useState()`).

Say I click on "Generate A", it will generate two "N1", "N2" and append to list.

When I next click on "Generate B", it will generate next three "N3", "N4", "N5" and append to the list.

If I click on "Generate A" again, it will generate next two "N7", "N8" append to the list.

My question is what would be the easiest way to keep track of the current maximum N number being generated.

The obvious way may be to have a:

```js
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
```

... and to increment it, but I was thinking I cannot use `useState()` because `setCounter(counter+1);` does not work in a synchronous way. I would need the reservation of the running ID to at least guarantee reliably that it is unique and incremental.

Anyone here can propose any *simple*, *elegant*, *reliable* solution to get this incremental generator?

Comment: Use a functional state update `setCounter(counter => counter + 1)` [demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-regular-and-functional-state-updates-2rtbk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something *almost* as simple as `setCounter(counter + 1)` with a functional state update.

```
setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
```

Example Code

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

const createId = count => {
  setCounter(i => i + count);
  const newIds = [...Array(count).keys()].map(i => i + counter);
  // Do what you need with generated ids
  console.log(newIds);
}

const generateA = () => createId(2);
const generateB = () => createId(3);
```

[image: Edit sparkling-http-fnysi]

Comment: Thanks for the functional state update method, I wasn't aware!  This is exactly what I need, as I need the newIds returned back to perform some other synchronous operation.

One query about this code though. Isn't there a (very) *remote* possibility, if both Generate A and Generate B clicked at same time (or any button twice), it is possible they may be clashing with same number? Because the `counter` may be used before the setCounter() callback is run.

Comment: The way around this might be to perform the newIDs operations within the setCounter callback: setCounter(count => {
  const newIds = [...Array(count).keys()].map(i => i + count);
  // Do what you need with generated ids
  console.log(newIds);
});
}

Comment: Javascript is *mostly* single threaded, so there's really no way two buttons can be clicked *at the same time*; one onClick event will be processed from the event queue before the other. About the state update, this is the problem functional updates solve as *all* state updates per render cycle are batched processed for the next render cycle. The functional updates use the value from the previous batched update. The demo I linked in a regular comment details this a bit more.

Comment: Ok, while it might be running single-threaded, but we also can't assume anything about when React internally will process the setCounter() setting state operations right? This will rely on that the setCounter() is being run immediately after each is clicked.

Comment: @AndrewOoi I don't have the exact doc on-hand, but I believe I've read that react processes state updates in the order in which they are "queued up", meaning, even if a user was able to click both buttons and queue up a bunch of state updates within a single render cycle, react will process them in order.

Comment: Yes, the order of queuing might be guaranteed for setCounter() but the code might still clash in newId. Example sequence: 1) click Generate A, 2) call setCounter() [defered]  3) use newIds,  4) click Generate B, 5)  call setCounter() [defered]   6) use newIds (clashing)  7) the first setCounter() executes,  8) the second setCounter() executes.

Comment: @AndrewOoi I really didn't think this would turn into a debate about JS/React mechanics (totally outside the scope of this Q&A, btw), but these are *synchronous* callback functions, placed in the event queue. When the callback for Generate A is processed, *all of the function is executed*, meaning, the state update is queued up and new ids generated. It's highly likely this update will be reconciled by react before the callback for Generate B is processed.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine max and numbers as when you set one you also have to set the other. Then you can use the object state value as 2 separate values by destructuring it: `const { numbers, max } = nums;`, see example code below:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [nums, setNumbers] = React.useState({
    numbers: [],
    max: 0,
  });
  const { numbers, max } = nums;
  const add = React.useCallback((howMany) => {
    setNumbers(({ numbers, max }) => ({
      numbers: numbers.concat(
        [...new Array(howMany)]
          .fill()
          .map((_, i) => max + i + 1)
      ),
      max: max + howMany,
    }));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>max is: {max}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => add(2)}>add 2</button>
      <button onClick={() => add(3)}>add 3</button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(numbers, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```